# Encrypt the images in resource folder +IOS SDK

Tags: ios, encryption

Anyone knows how to encrypt images in the resource folder? Is there any encryption algorithms for doing so? I'm using an in-app purchase application and some images can be seen only after purchasing that (all images are in resource folder). We can saw the files in .ipa file from windows by hacking it. How to encrypt those files and images in resource folder?

Comment: Did you check out [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html) already?